# SQL Group By in Update

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to update my ComContribPct in my quote table with the sum of ComContribPct in my quotemodifiers table . Each quote listed in my quote table will have a sum basically . How to do ? Right now sql complains about my Group By at the bottom line of my query. -- Jason

```
UPDATE q
SET q.ComContribPct= SUM(ISNULL(qm.ComContribPct,0)) 
FROM Quote q INNER JOIN QuoteModifiers qm ON q.QuoteNum=qm.QuoteNum
GROUP BY qm.QuoteNum
```

SQL giving me

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'

Comment: you have error ?

Comment: Sharing the error message would be step 1.

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'

Answer (score 0):

You query is  equivalent to this (and you don't have the problem of group by at the bottom of the update)

```
UPDATE q
set  q.ComContribPct = t.my_sum
from Quote q inner join (
    select QuoteNum, SUM(ISNULL(ComContribPct,0)) as  my_sum 
    from QuoteModifiers
    group by QuoteNum
) t on q.QuoteNum=t.QuoteNum
```

Answer (score 0):

You can perform the aggregation in subquery and then join it for update:

```
update q
set q.ComContribPct = qm.ComContribPct
from Quote q
inner join (
    select QuoteNum,
        SUM(coalesce(ComContribPct, 0)) as ComContribPct
    from QuoteModifiers
    group by QuoteNum
    ) qm on q.QuoteNum = qm.QuoteNum
```

Comment: @Downvoter - Please leave a comment? If it's because of the coalesce position, it doesnt matter.